# Robolectric: NullPointerException in setupActivity()

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric for testing my activities, but I'm always getting a NPE, when trying to setup the Activity with Robolectric. I have followed the guide from the [robolectric.org](http://robolectric.org) website.

Here is my code:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Ignore
public class MainActivityUnitTest {

    private MainActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Some other information: I'm using Dagger2 for DI in the project.
The exception I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.internal.ShadowExtractor.extract(ShadowExtractor.java:5)
    at org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(Shadows.java:1165)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.getMainLooper(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:42)
    at org.robolectric.util.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:31)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.<init>(ActivityController.java:35)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
    at com.me.myapplication.MainActivityUnitTest.setup(MainActivityUnitTest.java:32)
```

Comment: Try extend your class with Activity

Comment: Can you, please, post your MainActivity code?

Comment: Which parts exactly? I can't post the full code, since it's the property of a company.

Comment: Can you try to remove manifest specification from `@Config`? I suppose that Robolectric can not find manifest file correctly

Comment: Actually I have solved the problem. I had an `@Ignore` annotation which caused the NPE. I thought it just ignores the test when running the whole suite, and does nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

try: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3169

"AGP 3.0 includes changes made to better support unit tests (by including merged resources, assets + AndroidManifest.xml as first class citizens along with the Java code).

This can be enabled by adding the following configuration to your build.gradle files

```
android {
...
testOptions {
unitTests {
includeAndroidResources = true
}
}
```

"