# Robolectric 4.0.2 test are not running in gradle 3.2.1 with NoSuchMethodError: setUseLegacyResources(Z)V

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, gradle-plugin, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have upgrade my Gradle plugin version from 2.3.3 to 3.2.1 and than my robolectric  test start failing. So i upgrade the robolectric version to 4.0.2 with given changes in [Documentation](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/).

But still all my test are not able to execute with this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment.setUseLegacyResources(Z)V

    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setResourcesMode(ParallelUniverse.java:81)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.configureSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:235)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:230)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

This is what i have tried so far but nothing works.

1.https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4271

2.[Robolectric: NullPointerException in setupActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551056/robolectric-nullpointerexception-in-setupactivity)

3.https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2579

I have already filed the [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4283)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this answer on my issue

That Gradle config is picking up different versions of robolectric dependencies

It would expect that we don't need to explicitly depend on resources or shadows core since those would be brought intransitively. So try the following

```
robolectricVersion = '4.0.2'
robolectric : "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}",
shadowsSupport : "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:${robolectricVersion}",
shadowsMultidex: "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:${robolectricVersion}",
```